# How to add identity config <identity impersonate="true" /> setting in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

When deploying my core application on IIS, System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name returns IIS Pool user while i want it to return the windows logged in user .

Comment: could you try using HttpContext.User.Identity.Name

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation) you can know that "ASP.NET Core doesn't implement impersonation. Apps run with the app's identity for all requests, using app pool or process identity." And there is no equivalent of `<identity impersonate="true" />`.

`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` is designed to return the application pool identity. And if you want to know who sends the request, you should use `ControllerBase.User`, as documented in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.user?view=aspnetcore-6.0).